# How to make console log in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

I don't know how to make a console log in Android Studio?
Maybe like this:

```
Log.d(the message, task.getName());
```

The  `task.getName()` is simple the function of the getter method of the "task" object.

Comment: To print Logs in android use like this - Log.e("TAG IS ANYTHING","YOUR MESSAGE"+VALUE_TO_PRINT);

Comment: Try to search before asking question https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat

Comment: Use the specific line of code: ```Log.d("key of the message", "The message " + task.getName());```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Log.d("key of the message", "The message " + task.getName());` Than, use the debug in logcat! Press the logcat button in the androi studio and then choose the "Debug" module! Than search for the "key" of the Log.s!

See the link: [The logcat link](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat) Visit it to see more details !

Comment: Yes, use the debug allways you wark in Android Studio!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Log.v()`, `Log.d()`, `Log.i()`, `Log.w()`, and `Log.e()` for verbose, debug, info, warning and error cases respectively.

Format is as follows:

```
Log.d(String tag, String message)
```

Tag is usually the class name and it is mostly declared as follows:

```
private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
```

You can check [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log) for more reference.